# Using Saved Games API and Turn-Based Multiplayer API

Tags: android, google-play-games

On the Google Play Games Services developer website, it says:

Warning: Using the Saved Games API together with the turn-based multiplayer API could cause version conflicts because the save game and match data are not updated synchronously. To avoid these conflicts in your game, pick and use just one API to save your game state.

I am working on a game where I plan to use both APIs, and I'm curious if I will experience a conflict. I am creating a turn-based strategy RPG, where you can have multiple battles going on with friends (using the Turn-Based Multiplayer API). At the end of each battle, your character and soldiers earn XP and items. These are going to be saved using the Saved Games API. The two APIs won't need to interact at all.

Should I be concerned about this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, because it is coming from the Google itself. They put this warning to notify the developer that if they use Saved Games API and turn-based multiplayer API resulting in an error, these two API's will be the reason for that error and the developer can easily identify the cause of it. So they recommended that you need to pick and use just one API between the two to save your game state and avoid any error or conflicts in your game. Hope it helps you.